# Magento Error — Too many request

Tags: discussion, support, bug

I got this error just a while ago:

Kindly refer to the image below

[image]

> Why I got this kind of error?  Is it wrong to always visit this site? Or are there any rules that says, users are not allowed to always visit MSE? I'm just doing a normal or usual browsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue, I wrote to support and they replied me like below

[image]

If you are still facing issue after one day you should write at team@stackexchange.com with X-id and IP so team will resolve it. 
Thanks.